# how to do this equation?

Tags: equations, texmaker

I wonder how I can do this equation in this style, I tried to make it into a matrix, but is disastrous.
[image]

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{matrix} 
\frac{2}{3}\sinh{\frac{3}{2}t}&\longleftrightarrow&\frac{2}{3}\left[\frac{\frac{3}{2}}{s^{2}-\frac{9}{4}}\right]\\
        \downarrow e^{-3t}    &      \quad        &\downarrow s\rightarrow s-3\\
\frac{2}{3}e^{-3t}\sinh{\frac{3}{2}t}&\longleftrightarrow&\frac{1}{\left[s+\frac{1}{2}\right]^2-\frac{9}{4}}
\end{matrix}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Think about future users when posting a question, please. A question title like "How to do this equation?" doesn't describe (even briefly) the post content. Be a little more descriptive.

Comment: you really want to use a package when building diagrams like this.  otherwise it's a beast to get arrows of the desired lengths.  `tikz` is reliable and comes highly recommended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this with [tikz](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[semithick,>=Latex]
\matrix (m)[matrix of math nodes,column sep=2cm,row sep=1cm] 
{
\frac{2}{3}\sinh{\frac{3}{2}t}          &   \frac{2}{3}\left[\dfrac{\frac{3}{2}}{s^{2}-\frac{9}{4}}\right]\\
\frac{2}{3}e^{-3t}\sinh{\frac{3}{2}t}   &   \dfrac{1}{\left[s+\frac{1}{2}\right]^2-\frac{9}{4}}\\
};
\draw[<->] (m-1-1) -- (m-1-1-|m-1-2.west); 
\draw[<->] (m-2-1) -- (m-2-1-|m-2-2.west); 
\draw[->] (m-1-1) -- node[right] {$e^{-3t}$} (m-2-1);
\draw[->] (m-1-2) -- node[right] {$s\rightarrow s-3$} (m-2-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It's simple with `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
\frac{2}{3}\sinh{\frac{3}{2}t}
  \arrow[r,leftrightarrow]
  \arrow[d,"e^{-\frac{t}{2}}"]
&
\frac{2}{3}\left[\dfrac{\frac{3}{2}}{s^{2}-\frac{9}{4}}\right]
  \arrow[d,"s\to s+\frac{1}{2}"]
\\
\frac{2}{3}e^{-3t}\sinh{\frac{3}{2}t}
  \arrow[r,leftrightarrow]
&
\dfrac{1}{\left[s+\frac{1}{2}\right]^2-\frac{9}{4}}
\mathrlap{{}=\dfrac{1}{s^2+s+2}}
\end{tikzcd}
\hphantom{{}=\dfrac{1}{s^2+s+2}} % compensate for the rlapped fraction
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]